# infinitely many integers such that ...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $a$ be an integer. Prove that there are infinitely many integers $b$ such that exists only a  prime number $p$ of the form $u^2+2au+b$ with $u$ integer.

I could only think that:

We can write the form of prime number $p$ as

$u^2+2au+b = (u + a)^2 - (a^2 - b)$

but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Something seems missing about the grammar(?) Does it mean "there are infinitely many integers $b$ such that..." and then end with "there exist only finitely  many prime numbers $p$ of the form ..."?

Comment: If you can prove there are infinitely many primes, then there are infinite integers $b$, no? And yeah, the grammar is incorrect.

Comment: ok, I apologize for the grammar. but the solution of the exercise?

Comment: There are no infinite integers, all integers are finite. Although there are *infinitely many* of them.

Comment: "... such that exists only a prime number ..". this part of the text is correct.

Answer (score 2):

ok. In both cases $y = \frac{p - 1}{2}$ and
we choose $(a^2 - b) = c^2$ and $c^2 = \frac{p - 1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $x^2-y^2=p$ (with $y>0$ fixed) is only prime if $x-y=1$ and $x+y=p$, or $x-y=-p$ and $x+y=-1$. In both cases, $y=2p+1$ determines $p$.

Now choose $b$ such that $a^2-b$ is of the form...